# Customize search SHOPIFY

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to do a search function on Shopify that searches by collection title and product name.

But at the moment I don't know how, despite reading through Shopify's documentation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Shopify search only return 3 different types: `article`, `page`, and `product`. there is no search for collection.  you will need a third party app for that.
if you want to search for collection. see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66911459/how-to-limit-shopify-search-input-to-a-specific-collection/67011159#67011159)

For example, added option to search on a specific type.

```
<form action="/search" method="get" class="search-bar " role="search">
    
    <div class="form-group d-sm-flex">
      <div>
        <input type="search" name="q" value="industrial" aria-label="Search">
      </div>

      <div>
        <select name="type" id="search-category">
          <option value="">All</option>
          <option value="product">Product</option>
          <option value="page">Page</option>
          <option value="article">Article</option>
        </select>
      </div>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--regular btn--dark btn--fill" style="margin-left: 12px;">
      Search
    </button>
  </form>
```